# How to solve Error: "Deployment failed: RESOURCE_ERROR" (The GCF v1beta2 API is deprecated) when deploying serverless GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, serverless-framework

not sure why but succesfull deployments for serverless GCP stopped working with the error:

```
team27> serverless deploy -c serverless_stage.yml
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Compiling function "user"...
Serverless: Compiling function "volunteer"...
Serverless: Compiling function "clear"...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Artifacts successfully uploaded...
Serverless: Updating deployment...
Serverless: Checking deployment update progress...
..
  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: Deployment failed: RESOURCE_ERROR

       {"ResourceType":"cloudfunctions.v1beta2.function","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"message":"The GCF v1beta2 API is deprecated. See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/migrating","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","details":[],"statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/stageteam27/locations/us-central1/functions","httpMethod":"POST"}}
      at throwErrorIfDeploymentFails (xxx\team27\node_modules\serverless-google-cloudfunctions\shared\monitorDeployment.js:71:11)
      at xxx\team27\node_modules\serverless-google-cloudfunctions\shared\monitorDeployment.js:42:17
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.13.1
     Framework Version:         1.64.0
     Plugin Version:            3.4.0
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

As suggested in https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/migrating
I performed `gcloud components update`
Same error...

Here is my yml:

```
service: stageteam27

provider:
  name: google
  stage: stage
  runtime: nodejs10
  region: us-central1
  project: stageteam27
  credentials: /xxx/stageteam27keyfile.json
  environment:
    IS_PROD: 'false'

plugins:
  - serverless-google-cloudfunctions

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - .gitignore
    - .git/**

functions:
  user:
    handler: userMessage
    events:
      - http: user

  volunteer:
    handler: volunteerMessage
    events:
      - http: volunteer

  clear:
    handler: clearCommand
    events:
      - http: clear
```

Comment: If you land here with the original error (e.g. via Deployment Manager) the respective type change that has happened is `cloudfunctions.v1beta2.function` → `gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions` ; based on [the migration reference by `serverless-google-cloudfunctions`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/HEAD/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using serverless framework to deploy your cloud functions in GCP, this following reference might help you,

https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/blob/HEAD/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md

---

**Option 2**

The second is from the developers' point of view, which means that you need to make some changes to the serverless.yml.

```
1. Change the service name or change the function name to make sure this function is different from the older one.

2. Redeploy the functions.

3. Once it's done，you may consider delete the old ones.
```

---

In addition to upgrading the `serverless` library and `serverless-google-cloudfunctions` plugin to the latest version, you can try to rename the service to other name than `stageteam27` (e.g. `stageteam27-v2`, `stageteam27-new`, or `stage-team-27`).

In my case, only renaming the function cannot solve the deployment issue while the service name is still the old one.

Just one remark that the function name will now have the following pattern
`${serviceName}-${stage}-${functionName}`.

**EDIT**:

We can specify function name in the `serverless.yml` if we do not want to have such long function name.

For instance

```
service: myService

provider:
  name: google
  stage: prod
  runtime: nodejs10

functions:
  myFunction:
    # this will be the function name
    name: myFunction
    handler: myFunctionHandler
```

In that case, the deployed function name will be `myFunction` only. If we do not specify the name, it will be `myService-prod-myFunction`.

Comment: Hi, only one clarification: I HAD to migrate from serverless-google-cloudfunctions=2.4.0 to serverless-google-cloudfunctions=3.1.0

Comment: Regarding your remark, any way to avoid this \ change it?

Comment: @MTZ4 That's right, 3.1.0 is mandatory, even the version 3.0.0 seems to be still buggy. I'm not 100% sure but this generated name seems to be a new non-backward-compatible expected behavior by checking the following pull requests: 216, 207, 206, and 165. It is better to double check on their official Github.

Answer (score 2):

Google actually deprecated their previous version of the Cloud Functions API. There were changes made not so long to the Google Cloud Functions provider that you may nbot yet have so try upgrading the framework using `npm i -g serverless` and it should fix the issue. Failing that, try to see which version of the `serverless-google-cloudfunctions` module you use and upgrade that.

Answer (score 1):

When installing via serverless.com templates, `package.json` referenced `"serverless-google-cloudfunctions": "^2.3.3"`. Version 2.x is the problem. Reinstall the package with version 3.x.

I deleted that line in `package.json` and ran `npm install serverless-google-cloudfunctions`.

This installed versoin `^3.1.1` and my `serverless deploy` worked.

Answer (score 0):

`"dependencies": { "serverless-google-cloudfunctions": "^2.3.3"` } package.json change version '^3.0.0'